# Opengl shaders: Postprocessing a few object on the screen

Tags: opengl, shader

I try to understand shaders and framebuffers by making random stuff.

I have a cube floating in a scene in 2 colours: black and white (texture). I add additional colours to the cube and scene with postprocessing. 
This works fine, but I want that only the cube gets these colours, and not the scene.

I do that with this:

1. Bind the texture
2. Bind the frame buffer object
3. Bind the shader
4. Draw the background
5. Draw the cube
6. Unbind the fram buffer
7. Binding the shader to post process the image
8. Passing the colourparameters to the shader
9. Draw everything with: glutSwapBuffers();

I can add the code if you need it.

Comment: If you want to apply an effect in a post-processing step only to certain pixels, your shader needs a mean to detect which pixels it should work on. I can imagine several ways for that (i.e., one could use a separate buffer with "object IDs" rendered into it to be able to identify each object in the postprocessing pass), but I really wonder why you are trying to do that at all. It sounds like a very inefficient approach you are seeking.

Comment: I should have given more details :p

Comment: i have 2 arrays: the background and the cube. i only want the cube to be post processed

Comment: What are "arrays" in this context?

Comment: an array of vertices: a cube and the background

Comment: but that doesn't mean anything for that context. What I said initially still hold. The while concept of trying to do per-object posprocessing is absurd. Why don't you simply render in the correct colors?